# How can I determine the most current available patches for HP-UX 11.31 without a support contract?

Tags: upgrade, hp-ux

I'm working with an HP-UX 11.31 server which has been out of its support contract for about a month now. I'm trying to determine whether any patches have been released for HP-UX in that time that this server hasn't received, but I can't find an official list of released patches from HP. Is one available? Or is there another way to determine whether it is missing any updates?